# Há maneira de criar um slide com jquery que ocupe 100% da tela?

Tags: jquery, slide

Como criar um slide com Jquery que ocupe 100% da tela?
É para fazer um rodapé animado com miniaturas de imagens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, basta setar o largura e altura dos elementos com a largura e altura da janela:

```
$('#slider').width( $(window).width() )
            .height( $(window).height() );
```

**Nota:** Se a janela não estiver maximizada, quando o usuário maximiza-la, os elementos estarão do tamanho da largura anterior, pode corrigir isso com o evento `resize`, colocando todo o código responsável pelos tamanhos dentro dele:

```
$(window).resize(function(e){ \*Código Aqui*\ }).resize();
```

**Nota²:** O `.resize()` no final da instrução é pro código ser executado assim que a página carregar.

Comment: Não foi o que eu quis dizer, pois eu quero que os elemento façam o efeito animate à esquerda, se repetindo ao final da sequência. As imagens são 8 e tem 125 x 82 px, eu gostaria que o slide ocupasse 100% de largura, apenas.

Comment: As imagens irão para a esquerda todo o tempo, se repetindo sempre que chegar na última. Quero que se repitam até ocupar 100% do espaço de largura da tela, paralelamente com o efeito animate em ação. É isso.

Comment: @Harison veja se te atende: http://9bitstudios.github.io/flexisel/

Comment: É exatamente isso KaduAmaral!

Comment: Tem como fazer isso de forma viável sem plugin? Pois seria ainda melhor.

Comment: Com certeza tem @Harison, pois os plugins foram criados do "nada". Basta estudar e se dedicar que você consegue. Tente fazer e quando encontrar uma dificuldade no processo poste aqui a sua dúvida. ;)